# How to refer to the current state in FP?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, state, immutability, mutation

I've already asked that question but my explanation was pretty bad, so I decided to ask again with a better explanation and with actual code (I'll ask moderators to delete one of the posts). So let's consider the problem.

Following snippet represents rendering notes from array. However, during the **adding note** part, I mutate a state. So the question is: how can I add a new note in `notes` array without mutating? In other words, I want to remove `replaceNotes` and remain the same functionality. I know that it's possible to add notes without array at all, but I do need to update array with notes in due to the future reference. The ting is, in my original application I've got lists with notes, and while I switch between lists, I should get rendered notes that relies to the list I switch on. That's why I should keep the reference to `notes` array.

At the same time I'm wondering, would it be okay, if I just store `notes` in `localStorage` and then take notes from that data? Is it a good practice in functional programming?

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const notesContainer = document.querySelector('.notes');

const pipe = (f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args));

let notes = [];

const createNote = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight(pipe);

const handleEvent = () =>
   createNote(gatherContent, renderContent, replaceNotes)(notes);

function gatherContent(notes) {
   const name = prompt('How do you want to name a note?');

   return [...notes, { name }];
}

function renderContent(notes) {
   function render(note) {
      const noteEl = document.createElement('div');
      noteEl.innerHTML = `<p>${note.name}</p>`;
      notesContainer.append(noteEl);
   }

   notesContainer.innerHTML = '';
   notes.map(render);

   return notes;
}

const replaceNotes = newNotes => (notes = newNotes);

button.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<section class="notes"></section>
```

Comment: I _think_ that your definition of `pipe` is known as `compose` in the functional programming world.

Comment: I mean It'll be composition if I changed the order of functions as arguments in `createNote` and replaced `reduceRight` with `reduce`, won't it?

Comment: My understanding is that it is common that `pipe(f, g)(x)` = `g(f(x))` whereas `compose(f, g)(x)` = `f(g(x))`.

Comment: That's true. I wanted to write like that at first but then something clicked in my brain and I wrote `reduceRight` lmao

Comment: You should be able to delete your own posts?

Comment: I couldn't because a user proposed the answer for my problem. "Users have spent their time, helping to solve the problem and It'd be not fair to delete their answers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to create a simple task list app without mutating anything except for the DOM.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const section = document.getElementById("notes");
const template = document.getElementById("template");

template.parentNode.removeChild(template);

const render = notes => {
    button.onclick = event => {
        const name = prompt("How do you want to name a note?");
        render([...notes, { name }]);
    };

    while (section.lastChild) {
        section.removeChild(section.lastChild);
    }

    for (const note of notes) {
        const node = template.cloneNode(true);
        node.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue = note.name;
        section.appendChild(node);
    }
};

render([]);
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<section id="notes"></section>
<div id="template"><p>name</p></div>
```

For a detailed explanation, read my previous answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58642199/783743

---

You can use this pattern with `localStorage` too.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const section = document.getElementById("notes");
const template = document.getElementById("template");

template.parentNode.removeChild(template);

const render = notes => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", notes); // set notes

    button.onclick = event => {
        const name = prompt("How do you want to name a note?");
        render([...notes, { name }]);
    };

    while (section.lastChild) {
        section.removeChild(section.lastChild);
    }

    for (const note of notes) {
        const node = template.cloneNode(true);
        node.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue = note.name;
        section.appendChild(node);
    }
};

render(localStorage.getItem("notes") || []); // get notes
```

Note that `localStorage` should only be used to save state that you want to use across sessions. It's not recommended to use `localStorage` as your application store. That would result in both bad performance and bad code structure.

Comment: That's an interesting of way of solving a problem like that and I'll definitely use it in some places. But I'm still wondering is using `localStorage` a good practice in functional programming? It seems as the best choice in my case

Comment: Do not use `localStorage` as your application store. I edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was very helpful.